# Under a condition, $\frac{1}{b } = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{a_{n}}$ will never happen

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, sequences-and-series

Conjecture:

There is no  $b,\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ such
that $b,a_n \in \mathbb{N}^+, a_{n+1}\ge a_n$,
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}=\infty\qquad\text{and}\qquad\frac{1}{b}=  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{a_{n}}.$$
This is just my guess, and it would be nice if someone could give a counter example.

Comment: @DanieleTampieri I don't think $\frac{1}{e-1}\in\mathbb{N}^+$.

Comment: @gmvh you're right. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Can you give an example of an $a_n$ that satisfies the given condition? I only see something like $2^{2^n}$ which is not something one encounter on a daily basis

Comment: @LegNaiB You gave an example yourself I think. "$a_n$ must be something encountered on a daily basis" is not among the hypotheses. :)

Comment: This is not that an exotic condition, even in the context of such sums. For instance, for integer $q\ge 1$ and $a_n=q^nn!$, the sum is $\exp(1/q)$, which [is irrational](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Exponential_of_Rational_Number_is_Irrational).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Actually, this happens for all natural $b$. Notice that
$$
\frac{1}{b}=\frac{1}{b+1}+\frac{1}{b^2+b}
$$
and iterate this identity. You will get
$$
\frac{1}{b}=\frac{1}{b+1}+\frac{1}{b^2+b+1}+\frac{1}{(b^2+b)(b^2+b+1)+1}+\ldots,
$$
i.e.
$$
\frac{1}{b}=\sum_n \frac{1}{a_n},
$$
where $a_1=b+1$ and $a_{n+1}=a_n^2-a_n+1$. This is similar to Sylvester's sequence and one can easily see that this sequence grows doubly exponentially.

EDIT: To produce example for which $a_{n+1}/a_n$ goes to infinity as slowly as you want, use the identity
$$
\frac{1}{q-1}=\frac{1}{q}+\ldots+\frac{1}{q^n}+\frac{1}{q^n(q-1)}.
$$
This identity implies, for example, that if you got some finite sum like
$$
1/b=1/a_1+\ldots+1/a_k
$$
and your last term is divisible by $q-1$, you can insert (essentially) a finite geometric progression instead of the last term.
For example, start with
$$
1=1/2+1/4+1/4.
$$
Replace $1/4$ with
$$
1/6+1/18+1/54+1/108.
$$
(here we take $q=3$ and $n=3$). Then for $1/108$ you can take $q=n=4$ etc.

Comment: Thank you very much for your accurate and concise answer.And even more, if we add one more condition$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{a_{n} a_{n+2}}{a_{n+1}^2}=1$$,are there another way to construct an equation like this answer?

Comment: @LMZ yeah, you can construct examples with $\ln a_n/n$ going to $\infty$ as slowly as you want (and as smoothly as you want, I guess), see my edit